# GTA SA не запускается после установки DirectX 9 на Wine

Tags: linux, windows, directx, wine

после того, как я установил directX 9 на wine GTA SA не запускается и выводит сообщение с ошибкой(как показано на скриншоте).

Искал в интернете, ни нашёл ни какой информации по этому поводу(видел как решить проблему через панель управления, но вкладок как в гайде не было). Пользуюсь версией wine-4.0.3

[image: Ошибка которая выводится при запуске GTA SA]

Comment: Как ставили DirectX? 
Зачем ставили DirectX?

Comment: Ты же через `winetricks` ставил?

Comment: don Rumate ,да через winetricks

Comment: gbg, на первый вопрос ответил выше. Ставил для того, чтобы текстуры не были слишком тёмными